# Saving stripped text from csv file as a string object with Python

Tags: python, string, csv, strip

I'd like to be able to save text from a file that I had to retrieve from online and decompress (part of an assignment), in order to carry on with my next steps. Specifically, I'd like to save it as its own string object.

I can see the exact text I need when I print it in the following manner.

```
for line in seq:
    print(line.strip())
```

I just can't seem to figure out how to assign the stripped text to a variable.

Comment: `lines = [line.strip() for line in seq]` or `lines = list(map(str.strip, seq))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a list, and append each line of text to the list.

```
my_text = []
for line in seq:
    my_text.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: This has helped a bit! I have a follow-up question if that's ok... every line in the text I'm saving is truncated after 80 characters. It seems like every line is saving as its own element. Is there a way to also strip the "new line"/paragraphing?

Comment: Oh, never mind! Using .join() solved that. Thank you!